# C# Parse XML Child Nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a massive XML file; so big that I cant open in with any GUI program.

I'm wrtting a little program to parse the information I need out of the document.

I have a function that reads the file and for each node writes to the console:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\Events\Import\events.xml");
                var i = 0;


                foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Elements())
                {

                    i++;
                   Console.WriteLine(el.FirstNode);

                }Console.ReadLine();
                }
```

This is returning XML of the following structure:

```
<System>
  <Provider Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing' Guid='{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}'/>
  <EventID>4907</EventID>
  <Version>0</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Task>13568</Task>
  <Opcode>0</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime='2015-03-29T14:47:06.505465800Z'/>
  <EventRecordID>195943</EventRecordID><Correlation/>
  <Execution ProcessID='808' ThreadID='828'/>
  <Channel>Security</Channel>
  <Computer>somecomputer.com</Computer>
  <Security/>
</System>
```

How can I mdofiy my function to just write the EventID childnode?

Comment: call `Element("EventID")` on the parent `XElement`?

Comment: @har07 Could you give an example of this please?

Comment: A little LINQ could go a long way

Comment: Im new to .NET/C#, could you give me an example of how I can use LINQ with XDocument/Xelement @BenKnoble?

Comment: It isn't clear from the question, I *guess* try to change the printing line to be : `Console.WriteLine(((XElement)el.FirstNode).Element("EventID"));` ?

Comment: It isnt my forte but microsofts msdn provides excellent tutorials. And there are probably some good questions around SO

Answer (score 0):

If your xml is big then XmlReader is generally a better option then XmlDocument. XmlReader is stream based and don't load complete Xml in memory. You can achieve the same using ReadToFollowing method of xmlreader as shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can get elements by XmlLinq in this way:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\Events\Import\events.xml");
         if(doc != null)
         {
            var elements =  from el in doc.Element("System").Elements()
             where el.Name == ("EventID")
             select el;
             foreach (XElement item in elements)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(item.Value);

             }    
         }

         Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx